# How to call a referenced function from a js file in an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am referencing a function with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='../main.js'> </script>
```

inside an HTML file.

Now I want to call it with

```
<a href=# onclick="function();" ></a>
```

but it can't find the definition. When I declare the function inside the HTML file it finds the function. I can click on the reference of main.js and it opens the file, so the location is correct. So it should find the function as well or do I need to reference the function as well and not only the main.js file?

Comment: You need to give your function a name, you cannot call `function`, it is a reserved word for a method

Comment: Can you provide more context? What does the function definition look like? Is it in the global scope, i.e. `window.funcName`?

Comment: As I've said, when I copy the function into the HTML file, it works. And it does have a name. I just put function(), since it is just some function.

Comment: can you post the contents of your `main.js` too?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your are referring the JavaScript correctly. Check the path of the js file.

```js
//1.js inside the same folder
function test() {
    alert('clicked');
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>StackOverflow</title>
    
    <script src="./1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href=# onclick="test()" >Test</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The function does have a name in main.js and the path is correct, as I wrote. When I click on the path in VS Code it opens the main.js file. I did it exactly as in your example.